# jQuery Validate ErrorHandling

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) Plugin.
Now, if there is an invalid element this element should be cleared and selected.
Furthermore, the form must not submitted before it is validated. The code doesn't seem to work as expected.

What could be the problem ?

Here's my Code:

```js
$("#track").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    focusInvalid: true,
    focusCleanup: true,
    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "invalid",
    validClass: "valid",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("span[id=" + element.id + "-error]").addClass(errorClass);
        ion.sound.play("error");
        },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("span[id=" + element.id + "-error]").removeClass(errorClass);
        ion.sound.play("success");
    },
    rules: {
        prio: {
            prio : true,
            required: true
        },
        lagerort: {
            place : true,
            required: true
        },
        ident: {
            ident : true,
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        prio:  {
            required: ""
        },
        lagerort: {
            required: ""
        },
        ident: {
            required: ""
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your markup ?
or better if you can http://jsfiddle.net/ it

Comment: why dont use `$.ajax`? much cleaner ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vke1u6qL/

Comment: For what should I use `$.ajax`?

Comment: **Quote OP**:  *"if there is an invalid element this element should be cleared and selected. Furthermore, the form must not submitted before it is validated."*  ~  You just described the default behavior of the properly initialized jQuery Validate plugin.  However, we cannot reproduce your problem without seeing the relevant HTML.  A jsFiddle is great, but you need to edit your OP to include the HTML.

Comment: The plugin version in your jsFiddle is 1.5.2 ... that is many years old!  The latest is version 1.13.1

Comment: Hi, I have updated the plugin on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is unclear, but I've identified some issues [in your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vke1u6qL/):

1. You are including version 1.5.2 of the plugin which is many years old.  The latest version is 1.13.1 as per [the developer's website](http://jqueryvalidation.org).
2. > "the form must not submitted before it is validated"

   You've set `onsubmit` to `false`.  As per the docs, this disables `onsubmit` validation; so this alone is allowing you to submit the form without any validation.  You are [not allowed to set the `onsubmit` option to `true`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onsubmit), so simply remove it.
3. You've defined all custom error messages as empty strings, but yet you've set the `errorElement` option to a `span`.  This makes no sense.  If error messages are empty strings, then it does not matter what kind of container they have.  Simply `return false` inside of the `errorPlacement` function and you will effectively block all error messages.
4. You're using `highlight` and `unhighlight` to target a `span` with the `id` of the `element`.  Since you don't have any error messages and the `span` is empty, this line is totally superfluous.
5. You're using `highlight` to set a timer that triggers `focus` every millisecond.  When the form is invalid, this throws everything into an infinite loop of blinking elements.  I removed it because the plugin will automatically bring focus to the first invalid field.
6. You're using `highlight` to set the field to empty.  This will never work.  This function is triggered on every keystroke so even if the user starts entering the valid data, your code will wipe it blank immediately after the first character is typed.
7. That leaves nothing but applying the error/valid classes in `highlight/unhighlight`, which is their default behavior already.  Your over-riding options can now be removed entirely.
8. I activated the `submit` button for testing purposes.

Not sure if this meets every requirement, but at least the jQuery Validate plugin is working...

**http://jsfiddle.net/vke1u6qL/3/**

```
$("#track").validate({
    errorClass: "invalid",
    validClass: "valid",
    rules: {
        prio: {
            prio: true,
            required: true
        },
        lagerort: {
            place: true,
            required: true
        },
        ident: {
            ident: true,
            required: true
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function() {
        return false;
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. But now, how could I clean the invalid Field? This page is internal in our company. I want to fill out the form with a barcode reader. If the input is invalid, the user should directly scan a new code.  Furthermore, I want to play a sound if the form is valid or invalid. Should I use the highlight/unhighlight function for this?

Comment: @MarkusHartmann, [see the docs for how to use all options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  `highlight/unhighlight` is for toggling classes on invalid/valid fields.  For something to do when the whole form is invalid, see the `invalidHandler` option.